# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__debugf referenced in function "int __cdecl fld_new

Tags: visual-c++

I am upgrading my project from VS 6 to VS 2010, while building in release mode, I am facing the below error.

```
 1>Creating library .\Release\JfFrpF32.lib and object .\Release\JfFrpF32.exp> 
 1>FLD_.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__debugf referenced in  function "int __cdecl fld_new(char *,unsigned char,unsigned char,short,char,char,unsigned char,short,char,double,double,short,char *,char,short,short)" (?fld_new@@YAHPADEEFDDEFDNNF0DFF@Z)
 1>Release/JfFrpF32.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
 1>
 1>Build FAILED.
```

Please help me .. thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you paste fld_new from FLD_.cpp please

Answer (score 5):

Common problems that cause LNK2019 include:

- The declaration of the symbol contains a spelling mistake, such that,
  it is not the same name as the definition of the symbol.
- A function was used but the type or number of the parameters did not
  match the function definition.
- The calling convention (__cdecl, __stdcall, or __fastcall) differs on
  the use of the function declaration and the function definition.
- Symbol definitions are in a file that was compiled as a C program and
  symbols are declared in a C++ file without an extern "C" modifier. In
  that case, modify the declaration.

For More Information [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The link isn't available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, even though I used `extern "C"`, I got the unresolved symbol error.
The hpp was

```
extern "C"
{
class A
{
public:
    void hi();
};
A* a;
DECLDIR int Connect();
}//extern
```

and the cpp was

```
#include "DatabasePlugin.hpp"// Include our header, must come after #define DLL_EXPORT


extern "C" // Get rid of name mangling
{   
    DECLDIR int Connect()
    {
        a = new A();
        a->hi();
        return 0;
    }//Connect
}//extern
```

The problem was that I had not created an implementation for the `hi()` function. Adding it solved the problem. Like this:

```
extern "C" // Get rid of name mangling
{   
    void A::hi() {}

    DECLDIR int Connect()
    {
        a = new A();
        a->hi();
        return 0;
    }//Connect
}//extern
```

Having to declare `Hi()` before `Connect()` may also be significant.